# Why is my jquery/ajax post not registering in my php code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

So I am trying to build a single page application using PHP and AJAX but I am having some issues with my navigation.

I have a file `controller.php` that controls the page to be displayed. The code that handles a post request is as follows

EDIT: Forgot to mention that echoing `$_POST['page']` shows nothing

```
if(!isset($_POST['page'])){
    include('Pages/landing_page.php');    
    echo "empty";
}
else{
    echo $_POST['page'];
    if($_POST['page'] == 'landing_page'){
        include('Pages/landing_page.php');
    }
    if($_POST['page'] == 'forum'){
        include('Pages/forum.php');
        echo "forum hit";
    }
}
```

The post request is generated with `$.ajax` function as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#home_link").on('click', ()=>{

        alert("Working");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "controller.php",
            data: "page=landing_page"
        });
    }); 

    $('#forum_link').on('click', ()=>{
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "controller.php",
            data: "page=forum",
            success: function(){
                alert("Callback Works");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I know the jquery click is working because I get the original "Working" alert as well as the callback alert if I click on the forum link.

I am using the Netbeans built in PHP development server but I have also tested it on a proper apache2 server that is well configured for PHP and AJAX.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You aren't showing the page after you get the data returned from the `ajax` call

Comment: send data like this on ajax call `data: {page:forum},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question, this should work:

PHP: (all the same)

```
if(!isset($_POST['page'])){
    include('Pages/landing_page.php');    
    echo "empty";
}
else{
    echo $_POST['page'];
    if($_POST['page'] == 'landing_page'){
        include('Pages/landing_page.php');
    }
    if($_POST['page'] == 'forum'){
        include('Pages/forum.php');
        echo "forum hit";
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#home_link").on('click', ()=>{

        alert("Working");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "controller.php",
            data: "page=landing_page"
        });
    }); 

    $('#forum_link').on('click', ()=>{
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "controller.php",
            data: "page=forum",
            success: function(data){
                $("#container").html(data);
                alert("Callback Works");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You need to take the data returned from the function and put it somewhere, presumably into a container element.

If this isn't what you are trying to do, please comment.

Comment: I believe you are right if I was echoing the HTML to render. I could absolutely do that but I feel like I should be able to simply include the page I wish to display. The problem currently is that I am not even hitting the if statement. It's like `$_POST['page']` is constantly empty.

Comment: Try `console.log`ing the returned data. Are you sure nothing is being returned?

Comment: Hmm you're absolutely right! Data is returned as exactly what I was looking for, turns out I misunderstood the PHP include function. Thank you!!